# Keep ListView with Checkboxes synchronized with a list of Strings

Tags: java, listview, checkbox, javafx

I want to create a simple ListView and synchronize its selected items with strings contained in a list. I have figured out I can use the method setCellFactory(), I update the String list when items are selected/unselected, but I don't know how to do the opposite, updating the ListView items selection when the list of strings change.

So far I have:

```
ListView<String> selectedAttributes = new ListView<>();
String[] toppings = {"Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"};
        listViewAttributes.getItems().addAll(toppings);
        listViewAttributes.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(String item) {
                BooleanProperty observable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
                observable.addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                    if (isNowSelected) {
                        selectedAttributes.add(item);
                    } else {
                        selectedAttributes.remove(item);
                    }
                    System.out.println(selectedAttributes.size());

                });
                return observable;
            }
        }));
```

This makes the list `selectedAttributes`elements updated when the ListView items are checked/unchecked, now I want to update the ListView items selection when the List content is changed.

How can I do that?

Comment: You could use, for example, an [`ObserveableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) (rather than a primitive array) and register a listener to repopulate the `ListView` when the list changes.

Comment: What about 
    `selectedAttributes.refresh();`
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `selectedAttributes` is an `ObservableSet`, (or an `ObservableList` where you carefully check you do not add the same item multiple times) add

```
observable.set(selectedAttributes.contains(item));
selectedAttributes.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) -> 
    observable.set(selectedAttributes.contains(item)));
```

Here is a SSCCE with this approach:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.collections.SetChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class ListViewWithCheckBoxes extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<String> toppingsList = new ListView<>();
        String[] toppings = {"Cheese", "Tomato Sauce", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"};
        toppingsList.getItems().addAll(toppings);

        ObservableSet<String> selectedToppings = FXCollections.observableSet();

        toppingsList.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(String item) {
                BooleanProperty observable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
                observable.addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                    if (isNowSelected) {
                        selectedToppings.add(item);
                    } else {
                        selectedToppings.remove(item);
                    }
                    System.out.println(selectedToppings.size());

                });

                observable.set(selectedToppings.contains(item));
                selectedToppings.addListener((SetChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) -> 
                    observable.set(selectedToppings.contains(item)));

                return observable;
            }
        }));


        // example of a button that changes what's selected in the list
        // This selects "Cheese" and "Tomato Sauce" and deselects everything else
        Button justCheese = new Button("Just a cheese pizza");
        justCheese.setOnAction(e -> {
            selectedToppings.clear();
            selectedToppings.add("Cheese");
            selectedToppings.add("Tomato Sauce");
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(toppingsList);
        root.setTop(justCheese);
        BorderPane.setMargin(justCheese, new Insets(5));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

The way you have of doing things (with a separate list representing the selected items) gets a bit convoluted. At this point, it's probably easier just to define an appropriate model class for the items in the list which has the observable property:

```
public class Topping {

    private final String name ;

    private final BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public Topping(String name) {
        this.name = name ;
    }

    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return selected ;
    }

    public final boolean isSelected() {
        return selectedProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        selectedProperty().set(selected);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

Then the remaining code is much easier:

```
ListView<Topping> listView = new ListView<>();
List<Topping> toppings = Arrays.asList(
    new Topping("Cheese"), 
    new Topping("Pepperoni") , 
    new Topping("Black Olives"));
listView.getItems().addAll(toppings);

listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(Topping::selectedProperty));
```

And now you can select items externally to the check box in the UI simply by calling, e.g.

```
for (Topping topping : toppings) {
    topping.setSelected(true);
}
```

Here is a SSCCE with this approach:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewWithCheckBoxes extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<Topping> toppingsList = new ListView<>();
        Topping cheese = new Topping("Cheese");
        Topping tomSauce = new Topping("Tomato Sauce");
        Topping pepperoni = new Topping("Pepperoni");
        Topping blackOlives = new Topping("Black Olives");

        toppingsList.getItems().addAll(cheese, tomSauce, pepperoni, blackOlives);


        toppingsList.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(Topping::selectedProperty));

        // example of a button that changes what's selected in the list
        // This selects "Cheese" and "Tomato Sauce" and deselects everything else

        Button justCheese = new Button("Just a cheese pizza");
        List<Topping> cheesePizzaToppings = Arrays.asList(cheese, tomSauce);

        justCheese.setOnAction(e -> toppingsList.getItems().forEach(
                topping -> topping.setSelected(cheesePizzaToppings.contains(topping))));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(toppingsList);
        root.setTop(justCheese);
        BorderPane.setMargin(justCheese, new Insets(5));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Topping {

        private final String name ;

        private final BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        public Topping(String name) {
            this.name = name ;
        }

        public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
            return selected ;
        }

        public final boolean isSelected() {
            return selectedProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            selectedProperty().set(selected);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name ;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is confusing. Should the first part of code that you suggest be maintained? And, I have a trouble resolving this, I actually have two similar ListView's. I want to keep them synchronized (when one changed, the other changes too), your solution makes things very complicated.

Comment: @Joker00 No, there are two different solutions here. The first just adds those additional lines of code so that if your extra list representing the selected values changes, the check boxes update. The second solution gets rid of the extra list entirely, and just stores whether or not the item is selected in a property in the item. This is likely to be much easier to use. Not sure what any of this would have to do with maintaining a second list view with the same data: that seems to be entirely independent from what you are asking.

Comment: @Joker00 Clarified a little and added complete examples of each of the two solutions.

Comment: I went for the first solution, it worked like charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using for loop to compare String item to list by equals() method,if item is equal then set observable true using below code.

```
ListView<String> listViewAttributes = new ListView<>();

        List<String> selectedAttributes = new ArrayList<>();
        selectedAttributes.add("Pepperoni");

        String[] toppings = { "Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives" };
        listViewAttributes.getItems().addAll(toppings);
        listViewAttributes
                .setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(String item) {
                        BooleanProperty observable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedAttributes.size(); i++) {
                            if (item.equals(selectedAttributes.get(i))) {
                                observable.set(true);
                            }
                        }
                        observable.addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                            if (isNowSelected) {
                                selectedAttributes.add(item);
                            } else {
                                selectedAttributes.remove(item);
                            }
                            System.out.println(selectedAttributes.size());

                        });
                        return observable;
                    }
                }));
```

Comment: That didn't work. How do you specify which item you set true in `observable.set(true);` ?

Comment: "Pepperoni" is add in selectedAttributes list,so when load a listview then check by equal method if it is exist in listview then is select true.

Comment: This is confusing. I don't understand where to set a particular item in the list view to false.

Comment: @Joker00 This is same as above answer first solution. Only different like that, He set list value in button click and i have set in page load.I hope now resolve your confusion.

Comment: It's not quite the same, though: this won't update if the `selectedAttributes` are modified after the table is displayed.